# Using pgfplots, why do minor ticks disappear when I change the base in logarithmic plots?

Tags: pgfplots

Plotting the same thing, just with different values for `log basis y`, the minor ticks disappear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[log basis y=10]
\addplot coordinates {
    (0, 1)
    (1, 2)
    (2, 4)
    (3, 8)
    (4, 16)
    (5, 32)
};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[log basis y=5]
\addplot coordinates {
    (0, 1)
    (1, 2)
    (2, 4)
    (3, 8)
    (4, 16)
    (5, 32)
};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to make them reappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pgfplots can only generate minor ticks for `log basis y=10`. These are at positions {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} * 10^k .

Are you sure that you want minor ticks of sorts {2,3,4} * 5^k ? Sounds quite uncommon. If you are sure, you can post a feature request on sourceforge.

Comment: Thinking about it, I agree. I prefer to use `ytickten={0, 0.5, ..., 2}`, which gives ticks at 5^0, 5^0.5, 5^1, etc. when the base is 5. Thanks!